# How idiomatic is this Scala 36 Cube Solver?

Tags: scala

I've written a short program to find solutions to the [36 Cube puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/36_cube).

I'm trying to break away from my normal Java / imperative style, and would like some feedback on how I'm doing.

**Puzzle.scala**

```
package cube36

/**
 * An immutable class representing the state of a 36 Cube puzzle
 */
case class CubePuzzle(val board: Board, val availablePieces: List[Piece]) {

  /**
   * Add a piece to this puzzle, to create new instance of the puzzle
   * @param rowNum row to add piece to
   * @param colNum column to add piece to
   * @param piece piece to add
   * @param checkSuitable check if the position will accept this piece (default true if omitted)
   * @return a new puzzle instance, with the specified piece added
   */
  def addPiece(rowNum: Int, colNum: Int, piece: Piece, checkSuitable: Boolean = true): CubePuzzle = {
    val newBoard = board.addPiece(rowNum, colNum, piece,checkSuitable)
    CubePuzzle(newBoard, availablePieces.filterNot(_ == piece))
  }

  /**
   * Find solutions to the puzzle which satisfy the rules
   * @param solutionsSoFar
   * @return a list of all valid solutions
   */
  def solve(solutionsSoFar: List[Board]=List[Board]()): List[Board] = {
    if (this.availablePieces.size == 0) this.board :: solutionsSoFar
    else {
      val nextPiece = availablePieces.head
      val availableSpots = board.spaces.filter(space => board.suitable(space, nextPiece))
      val sols = for (spot <- availableSpots) yield addPiece(spot._1, spot._2, nextPiece,false).solve(solutionsSoFar)
      sols.flatten.toList
    }
  }

}

object CubePuzzle {
  // Have to put two pieces in 'special' positions, where they wouldn't be expected to fit.
  // No solution otherwise.
  private val startingBoard = Board().addPiece(1, 2, Piece(Yellow, 5),false).addPiece(3, 2, Piece(Orange, 6),false)
  private val availablePieces = (List[Piece]() ++
    getPieces(Yellow, 6) ++
    getPieces(Red, 6) ++
    getPieces(Purple, 6) ++
    getPieces(Blue, 6) ++
    getPieces(Green, 6) ++
    getPieces(Orange, 6)).
    filterNot(_ == Piece(Yellow, 5)).
    filterNot(_ == Piece(Orange, 6))

  private def getPieces(colour: Colour, maxSize: Int): Set[Piece] = (for (x <- 1 to 6) yield Piece(colour, x)).toSet

  def apply() = new CubePuzzle(startingBoard, availablePieces)

}

sealed trait Colour;
case object Red extends Colour;
case object Purple extends Colour;
case object Blue extends Colour;
case object Green extends Colour;
case object Yellow extends Colour;
case object Orange extends Colour;

case class Piece(val colour: Colour, val size: Int) {
  require(size <= 6 && size >= 1,"Piece size out of range")

  override def toString: String = colour.toString().head.toString + size.toString
}
```

**Board.scala**

```
package cube36

case class Board(val placedPieces: IndexedSeq[IndexedSeq[Option[Piece]]] /*rows of cols*/ ) {

  val row1Heights = List[Int](1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 0)
  val row2Heights = List[Int](2, 5, 0, 4, 1, 3)
  val row3Heights = List[Int](0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4)
  val row4Heights = List[Int](5, 4, 1, 3, 0, 2)
  val row5Heights = List[Int](4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 1)
  val row6Heights = List[Int](3, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5)
  val contours = List[List[Int]](row1Heights, row2Heights, row3Heights, row4Heights, row5Heights, row6Heights)

  private[cube36] def spaces: Seq[(Int, Int)] = for (row <- 0 to 5; col <- 0 to 5; if (placedPieces(row)(col)).isEmpty) yield (row, col)

  private[cube36] def suitable(space: (Int, Int), piece: Piece): Boolean = {
    lazy val spaceEmpty = placedPieces(space._1)(space._2).isEmpty

    lazy val height = contours(space._1)(space._2)
    lazy val rightHeight = height + piece.size == 6

    lazy val colour = piece.colour
    lazy val cl = placedPieces.map(row => row(space._2))
    lazy val matches = cl.map(x => x.map(p => p.colour == colour))
    lazy val colourAlreadyInCol = matches.contains(Some(true))

    lazy val rw = placedPieces(space._1)
    lazy val rmatches = rw.map(x => x.map(p => p.colour == colour))
    lazy val colourAlreadyInRow = rmatches.contains(Some(true))

    val unsuitable = (!spaceEmpty) || (!rightHeight) || colourAlreadyInCol || colourAlreadyInRow
    !unsuitable
  }

  private[cube36] def addPiece(rowNum: Int, colNum: Int, piece: Piece, checkSuitable: Boolean = true): Board = {
    if (checkSuitable && !suitable((rowNum, colNum), piece)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not suitable for this poition")

    val newRow = placedPieces(rowNum).updated(colNum, Some(piece))
    Board(placedPieces.updated(rowNum, newRow))
  }

  private[this] def rowString(row:IndexedSeq[Option[Piece]]):String = {
    val r=for(p<-row) yield p match {
          case Some(pc) => "|" + pc 
          case None => " _ "
        }
    r.foldLeft("")((a,b)=>a+b) + "|"
  }

  override def toString: String = {
    val border = "==================="
    val content = for (row <- placedPieces) yield rowString(row) 

    val folded=content.foldLeft(border)((a,b)=> a +"\n" +  b)
    folded + "\n" + border
  }

}

object Board {
  def apply(): Board = {
    val emptyRow = IndexedSeq[Option[Piece]](None, None, None, None, None, None)
    val emptyPieces = IndexedSeq(emptyRow, emptyRow, emptyRow, emptyRow, emptyRow, emptyRow)
    Board(emptyPieces)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Puzzle.scala

```
case class CubePuzzle(val board: Board, val availablePieces: List[Piece])
```

Case classes don't need "val" before field names.

```
def solve(solutionsSoFar: List[Board]=List[Board]()): List[Board] =
```

More idiomatic is `Nil` instead of `List[Board]()`. Although sometimes I use `List.empty[Board]` in case I change the collection type (`Nil` is only available on `List`)

```
if (this.availablePieces.size == 0) this.board :: solutionsSoFar
```

Instead, how about

```
availablePieces match {
  case Nil => board :: solutionsSoFar
  case nextPiece :: tail => ...
```

Also, I suspect the for loop in solve() can be rewritten so that you do not need to call flatten.

### Board.scala

```
val unsuitable = ...
```

This seems backward, why not just return

```
spaceEmpty && rightHeight && !colourAlreadyInCol && !colourAlreadyInRow
```

Comment: Agree on the case class vals, Nil and pattern matching. The "val unsuitable =..." was an attempt to use lazy evaluation to avoid doing all the checks every time - does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

A more scala idiomatic-way to write the for loop in your solve(...) method such that it is unnecessary to call flatten:

```
    val sols =
      availableSpots flatMap (spot =>
        addPiece(spot._1, spot._2, nextPiece, false).solve(solutionsSoFar))
    sols.toList
```

Essentially what flatMap is doing is traversing through `availableSpots` applying some function to each of its values, and concatenating the results.